# Is there a way to stop `View` from the native pipe from producing new tabs in RStudio?

Tags: r, pipe, rstudio

I've adapted to using the new native pipe in R and RStudio. However when I pipe directly into `View` it creates a *unique* new tab which has been cluttering up my window. Is there anyway to restrict the new pipe operator to only updating a single tab like the previous pipe operator (`%>%`) used to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`View()` via `magrittr`'s pipe receives object named ".", so i gets displayed in the tab of the same name every time. On the other hand, native pipe operator is a syntactic sugar and the name that `View` displays is more complicated and pretty much unique every time. However, you can solve your issue by supplying your own name, i.e. `x |> View("your_tab_title")`. If you wish to save typing, define a wrapper for `View` and place it in your `.Rprofile`.