# Changing the behavior of `View` in the .Rprofile?

Tags: r, rstudio, rprofile

[Per my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77485475/is-there-a-way-to-stop-view-from-the-native-pipe-from-producing-new-tabs-in-rs) I want to add this statement to my .rprofile to change the behavior of `View`:

```r
View = purrr::partial(View, title = ".")
```

However this statement causes an error, I think because my .rprofile loads before `utils` does, so I am instead trying

```r
View = purrr::partial(utils::View, title = ".")
```

which does not cause an error but is not working as expected. How can I give the `View` function a default argument for title?

Comment: Can you be more specific that "is not working as expected". What exactly is happening? If you are using RStudio, note that the IDE replaces the default `View` function so it's not running the one from `utils`.

Comment: I didn't know that the IDE does that! The unexpected behavior is opening in XQuartz rather than in Rstudio. I would prefer to stay in Rstudio.

Comment: Yes. You can get the function from `get("View", envir = as.environment("tools:rstudio"))`. It's nested in that "tools:rstudio" environment which should be in your `search()` path. Not sure when exactly it gets loaded. What was the exact error you got from the first method?

Comment: Using the first method, I get an `Error: object 'View' not found`